# How do I install 32 bit package in a 64 bit SUSE machine using zypper?

Tags: package-management, yum, opensuse, suse, zypper

If I have to install a package( 64-bit ) I use - 
`zypper install -y MozillaFirefox` which is same as `zypper install -y MozillaFirefox.x86_64` for a 64 bit machine.

If I use `zypper install -y MozillaFirefox.i586` it exits as -

`No provider of 'MozillaFirefox.i586' found.`

Is there a way to install 32-bit package in a 64-bit machine using zypper.

As in yum I can do `yum install firefox.x86_64` and `yum install firefox.i686` and both works for me and gets me the package with required architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a repository enabled that contains 32-Bit packages you would be able to install them. Regarding firefox you have to download the 32-Bit package from the [mozilla website](https://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/all/) as openSUSE is 64-Bit only since Leap 42.1 (13.2 was the last 32-Bit release) and so are the official packages. You can view the available architecture of your package by running

```
leap15:~ # zypper se -s MozillaFirefox
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                               | Type       | Version             | Arch   | Repository               
--+------------------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------
  | MozillaFirefox                     | package    | 60.2.2-lp150.3.23.1 | x86_64 | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update
[...]
```

EDIT:
To install a different architecture you have to provide it as a capability. An excerpt from zypper man page:

> The packages can be selected by their name or by a capability they provide.
>
> - A  capability  is  formed  by  "NAME[.'ARCH'][  OP EDITION]", where ARCH is an architecture code [...]

So to install a 32-bit package you would run:

```
opensuse:~ # zypper in -C MozillaFirefox.i586
Loading repository data...
Warning: Repository 'OS-13.1-Updates' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides libz.so.1 needed by MozillaFirefox-26.0-4.2.i586
 Solution 1: do not ask to install a solvable providing MozillaFirefox.i586
 Solution 2: break MozillaFirefox-26.0-4.2.i586 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c):
```

Comment: there is no 32-bit package available for opensuse after 42.1 and in suse after 12?

Comment: I can't tell for sure. Custom repos could still contain 32-bit packages, but you can search [here](https://software.opensuse.org/) for the packages you require. Just to be clear, are you talking about opensuse or SLES products?

Comment: I'm talking about installation of rpm using zypper in general. My question is if I have both 32-bit and 64-bit for a package, how can I install only the 32-bit or 64-bit using zypper. As in `yum` we can do it as `packagename.arch`.

Comment: I added that part to my answer (zypper in -C <PACKAGE>.<ARCH>)

Comment: What's the difference between `zypper in -C MozillaFirefox.i586` and `zypper in MozillaFirefox.i586`? Can you please explain this?

Comment: with -C you can provide a capability which can be the architecture or a specific release. If you don't provide capabilities zypper assumes that you want to install the latest package. Read the man page for section "install", it explains that quite well (man zypper).

Comment: So in both cases `zypper in -C MozillaFirefox.i586` and `zypper in MozillaFirefox.i586`, I will get the latest version of `i586` right? Until I specify the `Edition` with `-C`?

Comment: Yes, if the ARCH is known to zypper it will try to install it.

Comment: Will it result in conflict if I try to install a 32-bit package if I already have a 64-bit of the same package?

Comment: No, not a conflict but you'll be provided with a choice to change the architecture, something like this:


`opensuse:~ # zypper in MozillaFirefox.i586
Loading repository data...
[...]
The following package is going to change architecture:
  MozillaFirefox  x86_64 -> i586`

You should try it out yourself to learn the usage of these tools, you can still abort anytime.

Comment: Is there a way to install both the architectures. As in case of `yum` we can use `--setopt=protected_multilib=false`

Comment: I'm not aware of such an option for zypper. But I'm wondering what use-case would need two different architectures of the same package... Anyway, quick online search recommends: 
    "you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
much more problems)"

Comment: Does zypper have that option?. I have seen it only in case of yum. Can I get the link from which you got this?

Comment: Again, read the man page of zypper to learn what options and subcommands it has. This is the [link](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49348)

Comment: It's for yum, not zypper. My question was about zypper

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point out that even for yum it's not considered very useful, so it probably didn't make it to suse as I can't find anything like that option.